# Firebase Custom Domain Not Showing Latest Deployed Release

Tags: angular, firebase, paypal, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

**Problem Statement :** I am running `firebase deploy` from firebase `cli` to deploy build inside the `Public` folder of my *Angular8* application. This action deploys the latest release only to the default hosting `url_link` and not to the custom domain.

> Note: I am only learning how to code and there might be a good change that I am doing it wrong altogether.

I have connected a **Custom Domain** to my firebase hosting account.

[image: Screenshot of connected custom domain on firebase hosting panel]

I have added  **paypal donate** button in the latest release and this button is appearing default hosting `url_link` --> [web app in Angular](https://storytellers-union.web.app)

[image: Donate button appearing on default url_link]

**Issue :** the connected custom domain does not reflect these changes at all.  `domain` --> storytellers union

[image: storytellersunion not showing the donate button]

Your pointers in right direction towards the likely causes of this issue would be dearly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both links show the button for me, so it's most likely that you're looking at a cached version in the second screenshot.

Force a refresh in your browser (ctrl-F5/cmd-R) to make sure it loads the latest data.

If that doesn't fix it, it may be that one of the edge caches somehow didn't flush the old data. While this is uncommon, if it happens you can fix it by redeploying the site using `firebase deploy`.

If that still doesn't fix the problem, it might be worth it to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, you are right! 
I just checked it again and it is working. 
So to be sure, I again pushed the updates and it took some time before they reflect on custom domain. Thanks again Frank. :)